# Force tab to render

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to force a certain tab to render, even without currently being the active tab?

The reason i need to do this is because my extension uses chrome.tabs to open multiple tabs and switch between them, and whenever I switch to a tab which has not yet been active, the tab has not rendered yet, which causes a white flash to appear on the tab until the tab renders. The duration of the white flash is also proportional to how heavy the web page is to render.

What I've noticed though, is that if you switch to a tab which was active at least once in the past, the white flash does not appear (since it has been rendered at least once in the past)

I need to force a tab to be rendered before switching to it, so that the white flash doesn't appear.

I am writing on chrome version 38 (due to technical restrictions)

Thanks

Comment: Earlier I posted this exact question in the chromium group, and only later realized that the group has been deprecated.

Link to chromium group post:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/sO-tfsrnwl4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't control it.
The white flashing is indeed an annoying [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332566).

The only wild idea that can be implemented right now:

1. create a new minimized window with a blank url or `about:blank`,
2. move the tab you need into that window via `chrome.tabs.move`
3. now that the tab is active Chrome should render it even in a minimized window
4. then after a while move the tab back and activate it

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There's a problem with step 1 of your solution:
The "chrome.windows.create" method does not accept the "state" property in [version 38 of chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create), so in order to create a new minimized window, you must create the window with the initial maimizied state, and then in the callback use the "chrome.windows.update" to change the state to minimized.
This method causes a small flash as well, since the focus changes to the new window during the moment it takes to change the state to minimized.

Is there a way to bypass this problem?